# How to "reuse" the SSH connection created?

Tags: ssh, terminal, login, tmux, gnu-screen

Here's my workflow and pain point: In a terminal, I first use tmux and create 3 panes, sometime even more. In each pane, I do a two steps SSH to connect to the work server behind a bastion server. In each pane, I have to type several different passwords/tokens get connected. So it's quite time consuming to do it in all the tmux panes.

Is it possible that I can login in just one tmux pane and somehow "reuse" the connection in the rest panes, to save some hassle of repeated login?

PS.

1. I am on windows and use MobaXterm, but can switch to other terminals if needed.
2. The server doesn't have tmux installed.
3. And the GNU screen on the server easily gets stuck for some reason, so I can't really use it.

Please kindly help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look up [multiplexing](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Multiplexing). Not sure how that interacts with jump hosts.

Comment: You can [synchronize the panes](https://blog.amjith.com/synchronize-panes-in-tmux) so that keystrokes you send into one pane are also sent to the others.

Comment: (proposed duplicate adress linux configuration), for windows part : do mobaxterm have a "clone connection" feature ? (can't acces my right now), then you could use multi input feature.